# what can be the alternative for $('form')[0]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $('form')[0] in following syntax
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

I have following question regarding above syntax

1. What is the meaning of $('form')[0]?
2. Main Question: what can be the alternative for $('form')[0]? i have 2 forms in page

Comment: One of jQuery-less alternatives is `document.forms[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of this is the following:

find all elements on the page with the tag name `form` and take the first one.

If you want to take the second one just do `$('form')[1]`

Alternatives could be: [.get(0)](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/), also I do not see a reason for doing this, because in my opinion all of them are kind of straightforward. Although actually `.first` returns jquery element, not DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is the meaning of $('form')[0]?

This gets first form among your forms. If you want to get second from the you could do $('form')[1].

> 1. what can be the alternative for $('form')[0]?

There is various methods but what if there are many forms in your document and want to get some of them but you don't need to worry about the order of the form. You can get them by name like this:  `$('form')['your_form_name]`

---

If you want to use vanilla javascript then you can do any of the followings to get the forms:

```
document.forms[0] //gets first form
document.forms[1] //gets second form 
document.forms['form_name'] //get form which has name == form_name
document.forms.form_name //get form which has name == form_name
document.form_name //get form which has name == form_name
```

And if you google about this you may know more info.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$('form')[0]` gives the reference of the first form element in your
   document.
2. If you want to refer form specifically you can give an ID to it and    get reference using `$("#formID")`

Answer (score 0):

1. `$('form')[0]` returns the first for element in the page, `$('form')` returns a jQuery object which is not accepted by `FormData`, the jQuery object allows you to access its members using index, so `[0]` gives you the first element in the jQuery object, it is the same as `$('form').get(0)`
2. If you have multiple elements then you need to give an id or class to the form and use it as a selector like `<form id="x"></form>`, so you can use `$('#x')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

meaning of `$('form')[0]` is that if you have n forms in your page this selector will gather data of first form. 
and if you want to get rid of this way coding give an Id to your forms and then select each form by its id.

Answer (score 0):

1). `$('form')` is a jQuery instance which is an array like object with numeric indexes. You can access the first element from a collection with square brackets, by index `0`.

2). Alternatively you can give form a name and access it with pure Javascript by name:

```
document.formName
```

or there is a `froms` property of the `document` that stores references to all HTMLFormElement elements. So your jQuery code is equivalent to

```
document.forms[0]
```